# How do project management maturity levels relate to the introduction of portfolio management?

Tags: portfolio-management, cmmi

I am researching project and portfolio management. I want to use the P3M3 self-assessment in my work and wonder if there any limitations regarding project management maturity level on using portfolio management?

For example, should a company not use portfolio management until it gets level 3 of project management maturity? Or can each company establish portfolio management independently of its project management maturity level?

Comment: You generally won't see portfolio management below CMMI Level 3, but there's technically nothing stopping you from having it at any time.

Comment: Are there any sources of this relathionship so I can refer to them in my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Effective Portfolio Management

There is no formal limitation regarding when you can (or should) begin implementing [portfolio management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_portfolio_management) within Capability Maturity Model Integration (CMMI). However, as a practical matter, you will rarely see portfolio management introduced before CMMI level 3, or operationally effective before CMMI level 4. This is because *effective* portfolio management requires repeatable, defined processes that leverage metrics-based controls to select, manage, and terminate projects.

### See Also

- [Capability Maturity Model Integration (CMMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model_Integration)
- [CMM Levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model#Levels)
- [PPM Maturity Model](https://www.gartner.com/doc/2837917/itscore-overview-program-portfolio-management#a2100391857)